# not able to host machine's redis to docker rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, port

I'm trying to connect my rails app which is in the docker container and trying to connect that to host machine's Redis server which is running on port 6379.
I'm getting

dockefile
  EXPOSE 3000 
  EXPOSE 6379

```
sudo docker run -it -e RAILS_ENV=development -p 3000:3000 -p 6379:6380 <containerid>
```

gives error

```
Redis::ConnectionError: Connection lost (ECONNRESET)
when redis is running on 6380.
```

and

when I try to run Redis on 6379 I get the following error

with

sudo docker run -it -e RAILS_ENV=development -p 3000:3000 -p 6379:6379

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint vigorous_turing (2b5c8e2b4f5df5f1bfcccfdfc87fd5ea78c5c2643de4e00774e7dec67acbd8c4): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6379: bind: address already in use.
```

Comment: Is Redis running in the same container as your Rails app, or somewhere else?  What port is Redis itself configured to run on?  How have you configured your application to connect to it?

Comment: Redis is running on my host machine with port 6380 for the first command and tried with default 6379 for 2nd sudo docker run command,

Answer (score 0):

If Redis is running on the host and you want to communicate outside the container, docker recommends using `host.docker.internal`.

So instead of specifying `localhost` as the host in your Redis config, use `host.docker.internal`. Your Rails app will be able to communicate outside now.
`-p 6379:6379` is unnecessary

Comment: But "host.docker.internal" didnt work on ubuntu .